# custom component click message

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I am writing a little component which i derive from speed button. All i need to do is actually override the paint method because i would like to change the appearance.
Now i've reached to the point where i would like to give different background color when button is clicked. However, i can't find a way to catch left mouse button click message in my component.

What i've used so far:

```
procedure KeyboardButton.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.LParam = VK_LBUTTON then
  begin
    //Some code
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

Which doesn't work as when i click on the button Message.LParam is not 1.

Also i tried...

```
procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
```

Well, i know that CM_MOUSELEAVE is not a message that represents mouse click. But maybe there's a message like CM_MOUSECLICK??? I couldn't find it though. At all, can anyone please tell me what is CM_XXXX as i can't find anything from msdn? Seems like Delphi specific messages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correctly testing for a mouse event. Try this:

```
if Message.Msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN then
  // Some code
else
  inherited;
```

BTW, `TMessage.LParam` and `TMessage.WParam` are parameters passed with a specific message type (like `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`), and have different meanings depending on what `TMessage.Msg` actually is. There should *never* be a case where you get a generic message like `TMessage` and check only the `WParam` or `LParam`.

Answer (score 4):

The VCL already tracks the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP` messages for you.  The `csLButtonDown` flag will be enabled in your component's `ControlState` property while the left mouse button is held down on your component (if the DragMode property is not set to `dmAutomatic`, that is).  Your `Paint()` code can check for that flag and adjust its background drawing as needed.

Comment: +1 I also keep on forgetting this. I think this one is the more proper answer. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

You can just override the MouseDown and MouseUp methods. Remember to check the value of the Button parameter!